# EntryComponent error on 'ng serve' but disappears once file is saved

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

The project was working without any problems but after upgrading to Angular 12, I'm getting strange error: **ERROR in ConfirmDialogComponent cannot be used as an entry component** when executing `ng serve`.

Strange thing is that going to the module that has that entry component declaration and just saving it (forcing rebuild), removes the error. However, that works only until server is terminated and `ng serve` is executed again. Then the save workaround has to be done again.

That's the module with error in it:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { TooltipModule, TooltipSettings } from '@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip';
import { DialogModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { TabStripModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent, AlertDialogComponent } from '@reasult/angular-common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        GridModule,
        TooltipModule,
        DialogModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        TabStripModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers: [TooltipSettings],
    entryComponents: [ConfirmDialogComponent, AlertDialogComponent]
})
export class DesignModule {}
```

It is always the first component in `entryComponents` that gets the error. Even if I change the order of components in the array.

Not sure what extra details to provide - will edit the question once someone gives a hint.

Anyone has any ideas, what could be causing it?

Comment: remove the `entryComponent` from this module and add the components in the entryComponent section of modules where it is declared.

Comment: It is declared in Kendo UI package `@progress/kendo-angular-dialog`. So I believe I cannot do that.

Comment: May be you can wrap kendo UI component using a new component in current module and you can use the new component in `entryComponent`.

Comment: @JsNgian it was already answered below, thanks for participating!

Answer (score 1):

try going inside `ts.config.json` and define the following in order to disable compilation with Ivy

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  },
```

It is probably the ivy compiler during `ng serve` which is failing

As [the angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#entry-components) states

> Entry components have been deprecated with the Ivy rendering engine

Comment: Oh... Should have probably read the documentation first... Never thought this could be renderer issue. As per documentation, entry components are no longer needed, so the array can be safely deleted (just tested). However, I cannot accept your answer as Ivy is going to be the renderer for the future of Angular and just disabling it shouldn't be a go-to move. Edit it with quote from here: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required and I'll accept it. 